# VS 2015 Regex Replace, how to reference group by name

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2015, replace, find

I am using Visual Studio Find and Replace feature with Regex.
I want to append to 10 digits separated by commas line break. So here is my regex:

```
(?<x>(\d+,){10})
```

How can I reference to x-group? Something like below, but it doesn't work:

```
$x\r\n
```

Example input:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

Example output:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
20
```

Comment: Didn't `${x}\r\n` work? Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Yes, this works! You can add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `${<GROUP_NAME>}` notation:

```
${x}\r\n
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cx%3e%28%5cd%2b%2c%29%7b10%7d%29&i=0%2c1%2c2%2c3%2c4%2c5%2c6%2c7%2c8%2c9%2c10%2c11%2c12%2c13%2c14%2c15%2c16%2c17%2c18%2c19%2c20&r=%24%7bx%7d%0d%0a)

However, there is an easier way - remove the `x` group and replace with `$&\r\n`.

**Find**: `(?:\d+,){10}` 
**Replace**: `$&\r\n`

The `(?:\d+,){10}` pattern matches 10 occurrences of 1 or more digits followed with a comma. The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that is used to only group subpatterns.

The `$&` is the backreference to the whole match value.

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5Cd%2B%2C%29%7B10%7D&i=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20&r=%24%26%0D%0A)